# $y'''-3a^2 y'+2a^3y=\cos{ax}+e^{2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How to solve the following differential equation depending on parameter: $y'''-3a^2 y'+2a^3y=\cos{ax}+e^{2x}$?

I got this on exam and I even don't know from where to start.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, for homogeneous part, you may substitute $y=e^{rx} $

Comment: @Qurultay Characteristic equation is $\lambda^3-3a^2\lambda+2a^3=0$ and from here we get homogenous solution, that is the part I know, but how to do the rest?

Comment: Maybe first do the problem for $a=1$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $a \ne 0$ since for $a=0$ the DE can easily be solved by direct integration :
$$y'''=1+e^{2x}$$
For $a \ne 0$ we have the polynomial chracteristic:
$$\lambda^3-3a^2\lambda+2a^3=0$$
$$(\lambda-a)^2(\lambda+2a)-=0$$
$$S_{\lambda}=\ \{a,-2a \}$$
The homogeneous Differential equation has solution:
$$y=c_1e^{ax}+c_2xe^{ax}+c_3e^{-2ax}$$
You can also  easily solve the inhomogeneous DE:
$$y'''-3a^2 y'+2a^3y=\cos{ax}$$
Try  $y_p=A \cos (ax)+B\sin(ax)$

For the second inhomogeneous DE:
$$y'''-3a^2 y'+2a^3y=e^{2x}$$
You have to discuss for $a=2$ the particular solution is $y_p=Ax^2e^{2x}$. For $a=-1$ the particular solution should be $y_p=Axe^{2x}$. Otherwise the particular solution should be $y_p=Ae^{2x}$. So you need to express the constant $A$ as a function of the parammeter $a$. Plug the guess for each cases in the DE.